# Javassist cannot find classes generated by annotation processor

Tags: java, android, apt, javassist

I want to use Byte Code Weaving (using Javassist) to call a method on class generated by Annotation Processor (using JavaPoet).

I am using Javassist on Android (based on this example https://github.com/stephanenicolas/loglifecycle). Javassist injects byte code in post-compile time (Static Byte Code Weaving), so classes generated by APT should be available.

But when I try to get some generated class (I know it was generated successfully) from Class Pool:

`CtClass c = classToTransform.getClassPool().get("some.generated.MyClass");`

It wil throw an exception:

```
javassist.NotFoundException: some.generated.MyClass
        at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)
        at some.bytecode.MyClassTransformer.applyTransformations(MyClassTransformer.java:59)
        at com.darylteo.gradle.javassist.tasks.TransformationAction$LoaderAction.processFile(TransformationAction.java:90)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.processFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.visitFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:157)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:172)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:172)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:172)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:172)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:172)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:24)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:498)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:500)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:322)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.process(CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:56)
        at com.darylteo.gradle.javassist.tasks.TransformationAction.execute(TransformationAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.execute(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.execute(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.execute(CopyActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractCopyTask.copy(AbstractCopyTask.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
```

Did somebody tried something like this?

Maybe I am using wrong `ClassPool`, I don't know.

I also tried `ClassPool.getDefault()`, but this pool does not even have the application classes.

**EDIT:**

I found the problem. Javassist goes throught all application classes and ClassTransformer adds them to the ClassPool, when they are processed. So the problem was only with the order of processing app classes.

Is there a way to have all classes available in ClassPool, not just the processed?